# jQuery switching tabs content

Tags: jquery

I have some tabs who are supposed to show different content depending on which one is clicked. The problem, very simple ..is they don't work as expected. I've spent quite some time searching and looking this up but can't find the solution. I imagine it could be because they are inside different containers, but I am not sure.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f7sm63t2/

The markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li class="module current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
```

Would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me a hint as to where the problem is.

(Note: the tabs will be mobile-only, so horizontal scrolling is supposed to work only with a mobile device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ul#tabs` you are using `ul.tabs`.

You have  `<ul id="tabs">` not `<ul class="tabs">`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('ul#tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 })

})
```

```css
#container {
    width:500px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container-content {
    width:150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#tabs {
    height:90px; /* 40px - more place for scrollbar, is hidden under parent box */
    padding:0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hide;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
.module {
    display:inline-block;
    width:;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ddd;
}
.module + .module {
    margin-left:0px
}
.tab-content{
   display: none;
   background: #ededed;
   padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current{
   display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li class="module current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="module" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
  Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops! I knew it had to be something like that. Thank you so much for saving my evening :) I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me.